# Deploying Identity Server4 on Google Cloud (GCP) Doesn't work But works locally

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

Hi I was configuring Identity server 4 on the api project I am building and I am able to call the  https://localhost:2525/.well-known/openid-configuration when I just run the api project locally using visual studio(passing ttps://localhost:2525 to the authority variable).

But when I deploy it on GCP I am unable to call this using https://abc.devplatform.com/.well-known/openid-configuration (where abc.devplatform.com is the hosting address where the api project gets hosted. I also tried passing the above host name in authority but doesn't seem to work).

The code on my startup.cs looks like this:

services.AddIdentityServer()

```
            .AddSigningCredential(new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256))

            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)

            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients);

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")

            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>

            {
                var key=Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Test:Key"]);
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.Authority = "https://abc.devplatform.com/";
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)                  
            };
```

I think its related to options.Authority not set correctly here. What am I missing here?

Comment: What error do you get back? To reduce complexity, I recommend that you don't mix IdentityServer with the client and API's, because it makes it soo much harder to reason about and debug.

Comment: I am getting 500 internal server error on any api call I make that has [Authorize] attribute set. Also the hosting is done using kestrel in GCP and I have this configured in appsettings.  "Kestrel": {
        "Endpoints": {
            "Http": {
                "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:8080"
            }
        }

Comment: If you get a 500 error, then it is not an authentication/authorization error, instead, it is something else. See the logs produced by ASP.NET Core.

Comment: It is often a good idea to have a my.api.com/test that you can call without authorization/authentication, just to verify that the service actually work.

Comment: The 500 is returned when it reaches the point where it tries to get the token and null is returned and its an object reference error basically but the main issue here is its not able to find the endpoint(.well-known/openid-configuration) from which it has to get the url for the token endpoint. I have a call without the authorize and that works.

Comment: As I said before, "I recommend that you don't mix IdentityServer with the client and API's, because it makes it soo much harder to reason about and debug."  If you host IdentityServer, the Client and the API's separately, it is much easier to reason about and understand.

Comment: You need to post a bit more of your Startup/Program class, for me to be able to help you